# Functor between Category and its Free Strict Monoidal Category

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

Let $C$ be a category and let $\sum(C)$ denote the free strict monoidal category over $C$. According to Wikipedia, the operation $\sum: C\rightarrow\sum(C)$ extends to a 2-monad on $Cat$. Can someone explicitly construct the functor $\sum$? I'm a bit new to this area so forgive the naive question.

Comment: Do you know the analogous statement for sets and free monoids?

Comment: I've heard of it but do not recall the exact map from the set to free monoid.

Comment: So, the functor has an object mapping part, this is given: $C\mapsto\Sigma(C)$, and a morphism mapping part. In $Cat$, the morphisms are the functors, so I guess your question basically is: 'What is  $\Sigma(F)$ for a functor $F:C\to D$?'. Additionally, the statement goes beyond and claims a 2-cell mapping part, among others.